# Is there any way to visually divide the items in a comboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was thinking of some kind of lines between the groups or something. Are there any ways to separate the items into groups? Coloring them is an option but it's just gonna look bad.

Comment: Are you asking for a horizontal line between each item in the drop-down?

Comment: @JohnArlen

Yes, that could do.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a separator item into your combo box. You can use an item that displays an empty string, a dash, etc. Unfortunately, this is not easy in general when using WinForms. If you were using WPF, you could do this more elegantly.

Comment: This is an extremely easy way of achieving separators. However, you also need to add some logic (e.g. to reselect the previous selection) if the user tries to "choose" your separator item. Ultimately it's a bit of a kludge, but if you're happy with clunky UI it suffices.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to owner-draw your own.  Derive combo, set `DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed` and render the items:

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    if( e.State == DrawItemState.Focus )
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    var item = this.Items[e.Index];
    using(var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item.ToString(), e.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ControlText, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Y);

    base.OnDrawItem(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the visualization of the elements, but it is a complicated solution. Or you can insert lines (hollow items) manually, and you handle the selection, to revert if they are selected.

I don't think that there are any default solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was some sort of pre-made solution or function.